# Does using less variables matter performance wise in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, variables

Is there a performance/resources difference between these two?

```
$a = "foo bar";
$b = substr($a,-3);
if ($b == "bar")
{
      echo "bar!!";
}
```

and

```
if (substr($a = "foo bar", -3) == "bar")
{
      echo "bar!!";
}
```

In the first one you are using an extra variable, I always do this for making it more readable, and also making it possible to know the value when debugging, I don't like to do any processing in my conditions, does this really matter performance wise? am I using more memory?

I'd like to see how these two differ theoretically and practically, should one avoid using unecessary variable assignments?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Please define *"unecessary variable assignment"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference (besides a difference in the AST and/or bytecode) is that when you do `$b = substr($a, -3)`, you keep the returned string in `$b` until `$b` goes out of scope, then the reference is released and the string can then be garbage collected.

When you do it the the other way, the string is used in the comparison to `"bar"` and then is immediately discarded so the garbage collector can clean it up sooner.

Will this make a difference to you? No. Don't take it into account because it can't be overstated how small a thing it is. Code for clarity.

Comment: Additionally, if code grows, it often pays to use variables. Don't know/remember why exactly, but it often has a positive effect. Something like "don't fear using variables" as some rule of thumb.

Comment: @hakre: Not always.  Having the scope cluttered up with lots of useless intermediate variables makes it harder to reason about code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Sure, there is always a counter example. If you only need `$bar`, assigning it like `$bar = $unused1 = $unused2 = $unused3 = 'bar';` would be a drastic counter-example.

Comment: @hakre: Oh, I'm not even thinking of contrived examples.  I just mean things like `$tmp1 = $a + $b; $tmp2 = $tmp1 * $a - 3; $result = $tmp2 - $d;`.  Sure, you've maybe made the sequence of calculations easier, but you now have a bunch of otherwise-useless variables floating around.

Comment: I would consider `$result = ($a + $b) * $a - 3 - $d;` more readable, probably even moving the constant to the start (if you dislike to coin your example contrived as well ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, fewer variables means the program uses less memory which *could* lend itself to better performance. However this is such a minute point, given the processing power available and the nature of PHP. It's intended to be a scripting/programming language for speed, not extreme performance. Do what's most readable, that gets the job done in the least amount of *your* time, not the CPU's.

---

Check out [Jeff Atwood's post about the perils of Micro-Optimization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this case your just splitting hairs. So no it doesn't matter.

Also, if you are in the scope of a function, then the variables will just get garbage collected after the function returns.